# Change cursor icon when on certain calculated area

Tags: jquery, css, dom, cursor

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {

   if(e.pageX > $(this).width()/2) {
       console.log('im on right');
    }else {
        console.log('im on left');
    }

});
```

Plain and simple, it works, but when:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {

   if(e.pageX > $(this).width()/2) {
       $(this).addClass('horizontal');
    }else {
       $(this).addClass('vertical');
    }

});
```

It doesnt work (NOTHING CHANGES), am I missing something?

css for that matter:

```
.horizontal { cursor: w-resize; }
.vertical { cursor: n-resize; }
```

Comment: You're styling the window ???

Comment: Ty for pointing out, I canged adding/removeing class to body, it worked brillllliantly :D, but on firefox it didnt :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a class to a `Window` object. The Window object has no equivalent HTML element therefore you can't apply CSS to it. Instead you should use either the `HTML` tag or the `BODY` tag.

i.e

```
$('html').addClass('class');
```

The second issue is that you are adding the classes without removing the other class. Once the user moves the mouse to both sides of the screen, the `DOM` object that you apply the `CSS` to will have two classes, both `.horizontal` and `.vertical`. To fix this, use `removeClass()`.

i.e.

```
$('html').mousemove(function(e) {

   if(e.pageX > $('html').width()/2) {
       $('html').removeClass('vertical');
       $('html').addClass('horizontal');
   } else {
       $('html').removeClass('horizontal');
       $('html').addClass('vertical');
   }

});
```

**EDIT:**

By default, `FireFox`'s `HTML` element is not equal in dimensions to the browser `Window`. Since the `mousemove` event is on the `HTML` element, it will only be triggered in the area of the page that has content. To fix this, have the `HTML` element fill the entire screen regardless of content.

```
html {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @user690214 When using Firebug, go to the HTML tab and hover your mouse over `<html>`. Does the entire screen go blue? If it does, try modifying the code so it works with a smaller `<div>` instead.

Comment: It worked on my FF when adding new div with height && width : 100% and pos absolute and pointing out to this script, but it didnt with html height && with 100%

Comment: I noticed an error, the mousemove event should be on the `html` element, not the `Window` element. Change that and try again. (Technically it should work regardless)

Comment: Do what you will it doesnt work :D, for my example it seems to work only with element nested inside of body and has 100% of W & H(when using FF)

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/p3Rt5/1/)  Working on Firefox

That is probably because you are not removing classes once added

see if this work's for you

```
if(e.pageX > $(this).width()/2) {
       $('body').addClass('horizontal');
       $('body').removeClass('vertical');
 }else {
       $('body').removeClass('horizontal');
       $('body').addClass('vertical');
 }
```

I used `$('body')` instead of `$(this)` as you were adding class to `window` as pointed out by [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)

Comment: Using FF/chrome and nothing changes

Comment: @user690214 If you have Firebug for FireFox, see if the HTML changes in the source view as you move your mouse around the screen or using the console try to enter the addClass/removeClass manually and see if it works.

Comment: When viewed on Firebug, class changed from horizontal->vertical->horizontal, but it wasn't visible on the page

Comment: @user690214  this work's for me on firefox..  try it out  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/p3Rt5/1/

Comment: Maybe in newer versions of FF it works, but to think of all the user sea out there who does'nt use the latest

Comment: It's a styling issue in FF not a jQuery issue.

Comment: Yes you need to make sure your `body` have enough height and width so that you can see the effect

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a class to window. therefore replace `this` with `body`.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {

   if(e.pageX > $(this).width()/2) {
       $('body').addClass('horizontal');
    }else {
       $('body').addClass('vertical');
    }

});
```

Comment: I did that, and added classRemove, then got it to work on Chrome but not on FF

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but your code above looks like it is trying to add the classes to `window` which I don't think is possible. Try this-:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
   $this = $('body');
   if(e.pageX > $(this).width()/2) {
       $this.addClass('horizontal');
    }else {
       $this.addClass('vertical');
    }
});
```